# Install VMWare Tools on Mac OSX Lion - need to reboot?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, vmware-fusion

I'm trying to install Mac OSX Lion on Windows 7 by VMWare 8, everything is alright except the fact that I can't install VMWare tools for MacOSX Lion.

I tried installing it using VMWare's toolbar function "VM > Install VMWare Tools", but I got the error : "Could not find component on update server. Contact VMWare support or your system Administrator"

Another approach from Googling was installing it using CD-Drive with darwin.iso, like below photos. But it seems that the OS won't let me do that by asking me to reboot the system. No matter how many times I rebooted, the message kept saying I need to reboot to install it.

[image: Here the installer show]

[image: Mac OSX Lion required to check the file first]

[image: Then it required to reboot]

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to VMware's *Guest OS Compatibility Guide*, only VMware Fusion 4.0 and newer and a number of ESXi versions ranging from 5.0 to 5.1 support OS X 10.7 "Lion"  (from http://partnerweb.vmware.com/comp_guide2/pdf/VMware_GOS_Compatibility_Guide.pdf page 8):

[image]

That's probably the reason why VMware Workstation 8 doesn't provide any VMware Tools for OS X.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabeling “Virtualize Intel VT-x/EPT or AMD-V/RVI”.

In VMWare Workstation > VM > Settings > Hardware tab > Processors > Check the "Virtualize Intel VT-x/EPT or AMD-V/RVI", then try to install (darwin.iso) vmware tools again.